# How to save an image modified by some trackbar?

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to save the image modified by the trackbar. When I try to save it (using `imwrite`), it only saves the image before it has been modified by the trackbar. Not shown in the following code, but I have tried using `imwrite` in the `foo` function which did not work. I also tried returning the image and the `getTrackbarPos` from the `foo` function, but both values were the unmodified inputs.

```
import cv2


def foo(val):
    thresholdVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos('trackbar','window')
    _, dst = cv2.threshold(image, thresholdVal, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow('window',dst)


image = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

cv2.namedWindow('window')

cv2.createTrackbar('trackbar','window',0,255,foo)

foo(0)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Comment: clarify, please, where are you calling `imwrite` an with what arguments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an infinite loop at the end of your script recording key presses. For example, when pressing <kbd>s</kbd>, save the current `dst` image. You'll need another key as an indicator to quit the loop, for example use <kbd>q</kbd>. The `dst` image from your `foo` method then needs to be global to be accessible by the later infinite loop.

Here's some code:

```py
import cv2


def foo(val):

    # Destination image and threshold value must be global
    global dst, thresholdVal

    thresholdVal = cv2.getTrackbarPos('trackbar', 'window')
    _, dst = cv2.threshold(image, thresholdVal, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    cv2.imshow('window', dst)


image = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')
dst = image.copy()

cv2.namedWindow('window')
cv2.createTrackbar('trackbar', 'window', 0, 255, foo)

thresholdVal = 0
foo(thresholdVal)

# Add infinite loop, tracking key presses
# on hitting 's' key -> save the image with the current threshold value
# on hitting 'q' key -> quit, and terminate program
# Attention: Do NOT close the window by pressing the 'x' button!
while True:

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if k == ord('s'):
        cv2.imwrite('image_' + str(thresholdVal) + '.png', dst)
        print('Saved image as image_' + str(thresholdVal) + '.png')

    if k == ord('q'):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The `thresholdVal` variable just needs to be global here, too, because I use its value in the image filename.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.8.5
OpenCV:        4.5.1
----------------------------------------
```